# Firebase auth works on simulator but not on device (iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I used Swift 3 and XCode 8.

Here is the error:

> 2016-12-13 11:28:20.648: Failed to fetch default token Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://device-provisioning.googleapis.com/checkin,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2103, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.

The error happens in code:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: self.username!, password: self.password!) { (firUser, error) in...
```

Any thoughts would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: you were able to solve the problem?